# Unable to access Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When I tried to access jenkins using localhost:8080/jenkins I get the following error.

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /jenkins/. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Try connecting to http://localhost:8080 . If you get 404 check if jenkins has been started, if port 8080 is opened, look at log files, etc.

Comment: How did you isntall jenkins? What os are you running on?

Comment: I used the .pkg file for ios

Answer (score 0):

Check your webserver which is running, if you use apache turn on the apache server by going to right path

Check this out, [Apache web server to route HTTP and HTTPS](https://www.build-business-websites.co.uk/jenkins-behind-apache-proxy/) traffic to Jenkins. This helps too

```
 1.use URLs that lack the pesky port tag
 2.receive external port 80 or 443 traffic
```